# How do I display "Hello username" if logged-in on the homepage

Tags: shortcode, username

I am trying to show the name of the currently logged-in user in a small text like 'Hello, username!'.

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```php
<p class="vam">
    <?php if(is_user_logged_in()):
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>
        Hello, <b><?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?></b>!
    <?php else:?>
        Hello, <span>Client</span>!`
```

Comment: Your code in the question body is missing the `<?php endif; ?>` and `</p>` - are they just typo in the question? But other than that, your code is good, so in what template/file you put the code? Did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

try my variant:

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
    <form action="<?=get_home_url(); ?>myaccount" method="POST">                                            
        <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Hello, Client! Click to sign in:', 'theme'); ?>">                     
    </form>
<?php  else:  ?>
    <a href="<?=get_home_url();?>myaccount"><?php _e('Hello ', 'theme'); echo wp_get_current_user()->user_login;?></a>
    <a href="<?=wp_logout_url(esc_url( 'https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ));?>myaccount">Logout</a>
<?php  endif; ?>
```